# Объясните зачем нужен цикл for в данном примере. (Задача с codewars , нужно сравнить два массива arr1 и arr2)

Tags: javascript

Всем привет! Помогите разобраться в задачке с codewars. Я только начал изучать JS(выучил теорию), теперь пытаюсь практиковаться на codewars в решении задач. И я не могу никак понять, зачем нужен цикл for с переменной i, которую мы сравниваем с длинной массива (arr1.length), а затем в итерации увеличиваем эту переменную на 1 (i++).Т.e, каким образом Цикл for помогает в данном случае сравнить два массива? Скрин с условием задачи:[условие задачи](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZiC8.png)

Решение задачи:

```
 function arraysSimilar(arr1, arr2) {
  
  if(arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
    return false;
  }
  
  arr1.sort()
  arr2.sort()
  
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false;
  }
  return true
}
```

Comment: Измените вопрос, добавив код текстом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, это проверка идентичности двух массивов. То есть,

```
  if(arr1.length !== arr2.length) {
    return false;
  }
```

Это условие заканчивает функцию, если массивы разной длины.

```
  arr1.sort()
  arr2.sort()
```

это сортирует оба массива.

```
  for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++){
    if(arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false;
  }
```

а это проверяет массивы на идентичность и если какой либо элемент 1ого массива не равен элементу 2ого массива, то сравнение прошло неудачно, в противном случае

```
return true
```

означает, что сравнение прошло удачно и все элементы массива равны, то есть они идентичны.

Comment: Поправочка, не какой либо, а именно iтый, то есть первый равен первому, второй второму и т.д.

Comment: Первая часть кода проверяет равны ли по длине оба массива. А цикл мне вообще непонятен, т.е каким образом сравниваются эти два массива за счет цикла. Зачем переменную i увеличиваем в каждой итерации до длины массива и каким образом этот цикл ВООБЩЕ затрагивает arr2(второй массив). Это мне непонятно (

Comment: Смотри на пальцах. У тебя два отсортированных массива. Они одинаковой длины. Ты берешь i = 0, это первые элементы обоих массивов и строго сравниваешь их arr1[i] !== arr2[i] к примеру у тебя в arr1[0] лежит 1 а в arr2[0] лежит 2, 1 !== 2 и функция возвращает false, что значит что массивы не равны. Если проверка не прошла, то есть arr1[0] === arr2[0] то мы увеличиваем счетчик и проверяем снова, и так до тех пор пока массивы не кончатся или не найдется различие.

Answer (score 0):

Ну тут всё просто. i это счётчик, i < arr.length - условие выхода из цикла по длине массива, i++ увелечение счётчика на единицу перед следующей итерацией. Сам цикл сравнивает между собой элементы массива с одинаковым порядковым номером. Если они отличаются - значит массивы содержат разные значения.

Comment: То есть переменная i подразумевает под собой элементы массива ? Я просто не понимаю, каким образом i может быть связана с данным массивом и каким образом с помощью этой переменной сравниваются два массива между собой. В добавок , в цикле не указан второй массив , в таком случае тоже непонятно как i может быть связана со вторым массивом. Сори , я только начал разбираться , поэтому могу нести полную чушь )

Comment: В данном случае i это индекс элемента массива, его порядковый номер в массиве.